# is there a library to create zip files directly from Powerbuilder 12.5?

Tags: zip, powerbuilder

In a powerbuilder 12.5 I need to generate a zip file to send by email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an interesting new project on codeplex called [PbTools](http://myelkovan.codeplex.com/).  I've not tried it but one of the listed features is

> This application can make zip and then copy zip files.

It has a CDDL license and it says it supports Powerbuilder 5-12.5.

Answer (score 4):

Roland Smith from [Topwiz Software](http://www.topwizprogramming.com/index.html) has published a [zlib PB wrapper](http://www.topwizprogramming.com/freecode_zlibwapi.html) that consists of a dll and a PB object on top of it.

In the case where you would need to gzip streams, I have extended R. Smith component as [n_zlib](http://sebastien.kirche.free.fr/powerbuilder/en.html).